# Ubuntu 20.04.02 -display UNCLAIMED

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution

I have a intel i7 gen 11 with intel uhd 750 display adapter with Asus 24" hdmi adapter. The screen resolution at the moment show 1023x768 with aspect ratio of 4:3 (setting shown unknown display).

sudo lshw -C video--result as below

*-display UNCLAIMED
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Intel Corporation
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 04
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:50000000-50ffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

Any help to make it work?

Simon

Comment: You will probably want to use one of the newer interim releases, which has better support for the newer Intel hardware. 21.04 is a solid release 

Comment: @matigo: which interim release do you think will be good?